# ASP.NET Core Web API & EF Core Models with Foreign Key relationship

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api2, entity-framework-core

I'm developing a basic Web API project for education purposes, and I am having trouble with my EF Model relationships. I have 2 models. `Message` and `MessageBoard`.

```cs
public class Message
    {
        public long Id { get; set; }
        public string Text { get; set; }
        public string User { get; set; }
        public DateTime PostedDate { get; set; }

        public long MessageBoardId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("MessageBoardId")]
        public MessageBoard MessageBoard { get; set; }
    }

public class MessageBoard
    {
        public long Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }

        public ICollection<Message> Messages { get; set; }
    }
```

I've setup my DBContext and created a migration to configure the database. I generated two Web API controllers using EF Scaffolding. The migration appears to correctly detect the relationship between the two models:

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity("Asp.net_Core_Web_Api.Models.Message", b =>
{
   b.HasOne("Asp.net_Core_Web_Api.Models.MessageBoard", "MessageBoard")
   .WithMany("Messages")
   .HasForeignKey("MessageBoardId")
   .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
});
```

But, when I create a MessageBoard and then create a Message with the ID of the MessageBoard, they don't appear to link correctly. In PostMan, I am doing the following:

1) Post a new MessageBoard

`POST - https://localhost:44384/api/MessageBoards/`

`Body - Raw - Json`

```
{
 "Name":"Test Board",
 "Description":"A Message board for testing purposes."
}
```

Returns

```
{
    "id": 4,
    "name": "Test Board",
    "description": "A Message board for testing purposes.",
    "messages": null
}
```

2) Post a new Message

`POST - https://localhost:44384/api/Messages`

`Body - Raw - JSON`

```
{
    "Text":"Posting my first message!",
    "User":"Jesse",
    "PostedDate":"1/1/2019",

    "MessageBoardId":4
}
```

Returns

```
{
    "id": 2,
    "text": "Posting my first message!",
    "user": "Jesse",
    "postedDate": "2019-01-01T00:00:00",
    "messageBoardId": 4,
    "messageBoard": null
}
```

> I would expect that the messageBoard would not be null, and it would instead return the JSON for the messageBoard that was previously created. If I change to a GET method, it is also null. Why is it null?

EDIT: Here are my controllers. I removed actions except for GET and POST.

```cs
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class MessageBoardsController : ControllerBase
{
        private readonly MessageBoardContext _context;

        public MessageBoardsController(MessageBoardContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        // GET: api/MessageBoards/5
        [HttpGet("{id}")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<MessageBoard>> GetMessageBoard(long id)
        {
            var messageBoard = await _context.MessageBoards.FindAsync(id);

            if (messageBoard == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return messageBoard;
        }


        // POST: api/MessageBoards
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult<MessageBoard>> PostMessageBoard(MessageBoard messageBoard)
        {
            _context.MessageBoards.Add(messageBoard);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return CreatedAtAction("GetMessageBoard", new { id = messageBoard.Id }, messageBoard);
        }
}


[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class MessagesController : ControllerBase
{
        private readonly MessageBoardContext _context;

        public MessagesController(MessageBoardContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        // GET: api/Messages/5
        [HttpGet("{id}")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<Message>> GetMessage(long id)
        {
            var message = await _context.Messages.FindAsync(id);

            if (message == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return message;
        }


        // POST: api/Messages
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult<Message>> PostMessage(Message message)
        {
            _context.Messages.Add(message);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return CreatedAtAction("GetMessage", new { id = message.Id }, message);
        }
}
```

Comment: Please can you post the code for your GET / PUT action methods (where you query the db)

Comment: Sure. It's unchanged from the scaffolding so I didn't think it would be super helpful. One sec. EDIT: Added it.

Comment: @Jack Check your question and what you have accepted as answer. Have you asked the question correctly. If it is then surely the accepted answer is not  exact solution to your question. By the way, read my answer and then give feedback.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to [load related data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data)

So for example, for your `MessageBoard` GET - `// GET: api/MessageBoards/5`

Change from:

```
var messageBoard = await _context.MessageBoards.FindAsync(id);
```

To

```
var messageBoard = await _context.MessageBoards
                        .Include(i=>i.Messages)
                        .FirstOrDefaultAsync(i => i.Id == id);
```

Comment: This was it. I'm used to EF6 Database First where this is automatically configured, so I didn't think to do it on EF Core. I updated everything to use Eager Loading and it fixed it. Thank you!

Comment: @Jack no problem, please mark as answer if it helped

Comment: Just waiting on the timer to be up so I can mark it :)

Answer (score 2):

> I would expect that the messageBoard would not be null, and it would instead return the JSON for the messageBoard that was previously created. If I change to a GET method, it is also null. Why is it null?

This is because you are returning the newly created message, here only `MessageBoadId` is exists, not `MessageBoad` object. So you have to load the related `MessageBoad` from database using Include for newly created message.

Your `PostMessage` method should be as follows:

```
// POST: api/Messages
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult<Message>> PostMessage(Message message)
{
    _context.Messages.Add(message);
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

    var message = await _context.Messages
                    .Include(i=>i.MessageBoard)
                    .FirstOrDefaultAsync(i => i.Id == message.Id);

    return Json(message);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You've given the the application output and what the database looks like, but not the middle bit on how it saves/retrieves the data.
Without knowing what's going on in the middle, my best stab in the dark is that you've neither set your lazy loading correctly nor used `Include` to include the `MessageBoard` entity.

More info [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data) on what they are.